# Prove gcd or disprove

Tags: proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, gcd-and-lcm

I want to know how to prove or disprove:

1. For all integers $a, b$, we have $\text{gcd}(a,b)\le\min(a,b)$
2. For all integers $a, b$, we have $\text{gcd}(a,b)\le\min(|a|,|b|)$
3. For all non-zero integers $a, b$, we have $\text{gcd}(a,b)\le\min(|a|,|b|)$.

This is everything I want to know. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing to do is edit your query to provide the following info: (1) what is the background of the problem.  if from a book or class, what problems or previously solved theorems do you think might be pertinent here.  (2) what have you tried so far.  where are you stuck.  what questions do you have re your attempts. (3) try 3 manual examples, where all 3 #'s are positive, 3 manual examples where all 3 #'s are negative, and 3 manual examples where one of the #'s is 0.  See what happens and look for a pattern.  Please do **not** share ideas as a comment.

Comment: Hint: For positive integer $d$ and $n$, if $d$ divides $n$ then $d\le n$

Comment: You should also state your definition of the gcd, which is presumably defined on $\Bbb Z,\,$ e.g. so we know what your definition yields for $\,\gcd(0,0)\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque  from the OP's use of the modulus symbol, I think he did mean the usually seen GCD.